# Calling method on object in NSPredicate with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a 'position' entity with a to-many relationship to 'employee's. I want to use `NSPredicate` to do something like this

```
[position.employees containsObject:meEmployee]
```

There is a call to perform `NSPredicate` with block, but sadly it can't be used  with CoreData.

How can I do this?

Comment: How you fetch core data entity without using predicate ?

Comment: Show how you tried to use a predicate so far

Comment: I just load all the positions, and then filter them in by using nspredicate with block on that array

Comment: The `NSFetchRequest` has a `NSPredicate` property you can add in. Put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching `position` entities with any `employees` matching `meEmployee` then you can use a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFornat:@"ANY employees == %@", meEmployee];
```

But if the inverse relationship for `employees` is `position`, you can achieve the same with:

```
meEmployee.position
```